# Is it possible that IPv4 format IP address is really on a (ipv6 format) DNSv6 server?

Tags: dns, ip-address, ipv6

Is it possible that an IPv4 format IP address is based on a (IPv6 format) DNSv6 server?

How would I determine this?

Comment: I think I speak for everyone when I say: Huh?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're trying to ask is *"Can an DNSv6 server distribute IPv4 addresses?"*, and the answer is yes, it can! To understand it better, there are two different types of basic records that differentiate IPv4 from IPv6 records: `A` records and `AAAA` records. If a DNS server receives a query like this:

```
google.ca.              IN  A
```

Then the server will respond with

```
google.ca.        300   IN  A     173.194.32.104
```

because the client is asking for the `A` record, which is an IPv4 record. However, if the DNS server receives a query like this,

```
ipv6.google.com.          IN  AAAA
```

then the server will respond with the IPv6 address, as the client requested the `AAAA` record:

```
ipv6.google.com.    300   IN  AAAA  2001:4860:800b::93
```

Hope that helps!